# Objective-C category method available to subclasses?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, categories

I have the following category:

```
@interface UIViewController (Additions)

- (void)exampleMethod;

@end

-----

#import "UIViewController+Additions.h"

@implementation UIViewController (Additions)

- (void)exampleMethod {
    NSLog(@"Example.");
}

@end
```

I also have the following abstract class:

```
@interface DFAbstractViewController : UIViewController

@end

-----

#import "DFAbstractViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+Additions.h"

@implementation DFAbstractViewController

@end
```

And here's the concrete class:

```
#import "DFAbstractViewController.h"

@interface DFConcreteViewController : DFAbstractViewController

@end

-----

#import "DFConcreteViewController.h"

@implementation DFConcreteViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self exampleMethod];
}

@end
```

Okay. So it's my understanding that the concrete class, `DFConcreteViewController`, can use methods imported from a category in its superclass, `DFAbstractViewController`. This is correct, because the method call works as expected.

The problem is Xcode is giving me the following warning: `'DFConcreteViewController' may not respond to '-exampleMethod'`.

I don't see how this method and its availability to `DFConcreteViewController` isn't completely clear to the compiler? Perhaps I've misunderstood something about categories?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right. I figured it out. It was an elementary mistake and one for which I feel rather foolish. If you want your category methods to be visible to subclasses, make sure to **import your category in your header**:

```
#import "UIViewController+Additions.h"

@interface DFAbstractViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Comment: Been having the same problem and came across your post in an effort to resolve the issue.  However, I am including the correct header (class+category) and still getting the compiler warning.

Comment: Matt, are you importing the category in the header file (.h) rather than the implementation? The compiler can only see superclass category methods when the categories are imported in the .h file.